# waitpid() returns -1 if fopen() exists

Tags: c, process, fopen, waitpid

i was wondering why `waitpid()` returns -1 while `fopen()` exists.

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("abc.txt", "r");
fclose(fp);

pid_t pid = fork ();
if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
    printf ("child %d\n", getpid());
}
else {                  /* parent process */
    pid_t pid2 = waitpid (pid);
    printf ("parent %d\n", pid2);
}
```

`pid2` equals to -1 from the above example, but it becomes the same number as `pid` (child process number) if i eliminate `fopen()`.
thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're ignoring the error, so it's impossible to tell.

My best guess is that your `waitpid` call is interrupted by the CHLD signal from the dead child.

Test the error code to make sure:

```
int status;
pid_t pid2;
while ((p = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) == -1)
{
    printf("waitpid error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
printf("reaped child: %d\n", pid2);
```

If you don't care about `SIGCHLD`, block the signal before doing the forking.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! the code works fine if i use `waitpid(pid, &status, 0)`. i'm not sure why i can use `waitpid(pid)` without `fopen()` though.

Comment: @user1322538: Are you writing 1972-style C? That isn't type checked, so it's *your* responsibility to read the manuals and figure out your system APIs.

Comment: that was my bad, i thought `waitpid()` works like `wait()` and the compiler didn't give me any error or warning.

Comment: @user1322538: C is a terrible language to use if you're not willing to do a *lot* of leg work.